# How to initialize a property of a mapped typed in Typescript

Tags: typescript, mapped-types

Let's say I want to model a Fruit Shop in Typescript: I have a union type of string literals:

```js
type Fruit = "apple" | "banana" | "cherry"
```

I have a fruit shop with a price list and stock register:

```js
interface FruitShop1 {
  priceList: {
    apple: number,
    banana: number,
    cherry: number
  }
  stock: {
    apple: number,
    banana: number,
    cherry: number
  }
}
```

Since I will want to add lots of fruit later and I don't want to duplicate the properties manually on the `priceList` and `stock` properties, so I modified the `FruitShop1` interface to use a mapped types based off `Fruit`:

```js
interface FruitShop2 {
  priceList: { [fruit in Fruit]: number }
  stock: { [fruit in Fruit]: number }
}
```

I create my class implemeting `FruitShop`:

```js
class FruitShopImpl implements FruitShop2 {
  priceList: { apple: number; banana: number; cherry: number; };
  stock: { apple: number; banana: number; cherry: number; };
}
```

However, I need to initialize `pricelist` and `stock`. How do I do this?

[image]

What I'd like is for every property in `priceList` be initialized to 1 and every property in `stock` to be initialized to 0.

I've tried interating over every property in a constructor, but this produces errors I think because `priceList` isn't initialized so it has no properties to iterate over. This feels like a chicken-and-egg catch-22 problem. Is there a solution, without manually initializing each property individually?

[image]

Comment: Can you please share a minimal reproducible example as a typescript playground link? This makes it easier to try out stuff

Comment: you did not share FruitShop2

Comment: Let me know if [this](https://tsplay.dev/mpL9am) works for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've gone for a similar solution as suggested by @soffyo, but instead of using an array I'm using an enum backed by enums. Here's my code:

```js
enum Fruits {
  Apple = "apple",
  Banana = "banana",
  Cherry = "cherry"
}

interface IFruitShop {
  prices: { [fruit in Fruits]: number }
  stock: { [fruit in Fruits]: number }
}

class FruitShop implements IFruitShop {
  prices: IFruitShop['prices'];
  stock: IFruitShop['stock'];

  constructor() {
    this.prices = {} as { [fruit in Fruits]: number };
    this.stock = {} as { [fruit in Fruits]: number };
    Object.keys(Fruits).forEach(f => {
      this.prices[f as Fruits] = 1;
      this.stock[f as Fruits] = 0;
    });
  }
}
```

[Typscript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAYgTmAlgFwM5QN4FgBQUoCCADkQDbBQC8UARAIYnk0A0u+AQnSF3VbQEY9uLNlADCAC2Bw4ATz40AxlJmyauAL65cyWUQrwkyPoZSoA3NpyIQyaQDM6iigElTyAMoSA9kUyiiOERnVAAuTCgAbXsEFCgbWFjkAF1w8Ah+aSgtPChUZG9FAGtwjCiYo3iQRKNUqHTMuGzNK0VSOlR0dy9feIgyYAhQNCg3JJ6-bFzA4OAw0e6fIkiAchmQleTLXPzCkoXxpdXd4s3t0UVvEHyERQK4AAoASn9c-GQJRFQAOnW5vgwGigHQi0SSVRqKDqDSyGm2+Henx+JyKAKBILKYMqCXc0MgjWy8IRAHl+AArYB3b5FYCyVAPdyoJ7fezeOAAUScEge9ioAD5XgiER8vr8giFosCuklknwAIxEoUi5EFYqSkG4vgABkV2SeRJyOVwl2uxgqKAmfBAwAA7pDPEtntsTahvORvqRvABzHmHXz63BAA)

I think string enum could be an advantage for me in my actual project.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a type to produce runtime values, so you have to create a real array

```js
const Fruit = [
    "apple" as const, 
    "banana" as const, 
    "cherry" as const
]
```

Using `as const` assertion, you are assigning a definite value as a type which can be used by other types

```js
interface FruitCost {
  priceList: { [k in typeof Fruit extends (infer f)[] ? f : never]: number }
  stock: { [k in typeof Fruit extends (infer f)[] ? f : never]: number }
}
```

Now you can initialise `priceList` and `stock` as empty objects and add properties to them in the constructor

```js
class FruitShopImpl implements FruitCost {
  priceList = {} as { [k in typeof Fruit extends (infer f)[] ? f : never]: number }
  stock = {} as { [k in typeof Fruit extends (infer f)[] ? f : never]: number }
  constructor() {
    for (const k of Fruit) {
        this.priceList[k] = 1
        this.stock[k] = 0
    }
  }
}
```

This will produce

```js
FruitShopImpl: {
  "priceList": {
    "apple": 1,
    "banana": 1,
    "cherry": 1
  },
  "stock": {
    "apple": 0,
    "banana": 0,
    "cherry": 0
  }
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAYgJwK4EtYF4YG0BQN8wBEAhgA6kA2ApoTMRDKJFADQx4GEBGxYvxteo3DQ2HfIWAALKggQBPQQybQcAXRw4UYKLIBmxYFXjI0AYRDQYAbw6kEKIwBkU0AFw3sAaxjaYUeVIqED0TVFgqAA9dMAATBgAKbT1ZGD0ASiw1GAB+NJgPMCoAN1k1QqQAWy5UgF8OaBBgLw9rb18wf0Dg0MRwmCiY+JgksBSENMzsvNDCkrKK6rqcepxgCnoGPrQAZSkQUgBJSspfE+pKqh0t0ygLK1t8e0cqFytMa1q6BjasHz8AkEQmE0ANoldhqNxpMsrl8nNSghyjAwFUahN6vhGs0YB8vkJfv9OoCeiCIuC4olkqkMrCZgUUfMkYt0TBMcJmMhgFAQAgEukbOI0ryRipYD5gdsoALHgQ5VApK4AHTPZyuKB-bKYACMQvliogSuxXk1uJgAAYhez6qsVCBqEqKCAAOYJIoAdzJewOx0o-JVDjV0HSQA)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the type to construct the object at runtime. However, you can define an array of fruits and derive the `Fruit` type from that. Then you can later on use this array to initialize it at runtime with [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

However, I didn't manage to do it without the type assertion in the reduce call, as we initialize it with `{}` which should have the type `Partial<FruitCost>` and only at the end really is of type `FruitCost`.

```js
const fruits = ['apple', 'banana'] as const

type Fruits = (typeof fruits)[number]

interface IFruitCost {
  prices: { [fruit in Fruits]: number }
  stock: { [fruit in Fruits]: number }
}

class FruitCost implements IFruitCost {
  prices: FruitCost['prices']
  stock: FruitCost['stock']

  constructor() {
    this.prices = fruits.reduce((prices, fruit) => {
      prices[fruit] = 1
      return prices
    }, {} as FruitCost['prices'])

    this.stock = fruits.reduce((stock, fruit) => {
      stock[fruit] = 0
      return stock
    }, {} as FruitCost['stock'])
  }
}
```

Here is the [playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgJwK4EsoRgXhgbQOQCGADkQDYCmeANDHgEYFiMF4C6MBGokUAsAFACoATyLkYAMWRoM2ABQixIOPGnoAlDjBIAtnXIJWAgSjBQDcAsHEBJKaigBhENBgBvATBhEEKaxAAud1xEBxhTSTUIViDtPQMYAF9PGGgQYABrILcQtXCwSIdo2N19BCSBZMF+YFJODHs0Z1cUHTJyHXIzDDs1ZtgPfi8fP3JAwqaXKHwR-zYUtMygxqcp-EWM+eqvbmhkYCgQBDl1dxSvKAALFAgAOlmxrFUi24RyABMkazk5B4gaUJoU6YAB8ZyGXkhfxwgKg7GwAEZzpC3lAkAgCn9kYkaG5EhwGn01ng-mx1MYIRdrncNk9YXc3p9vnINgC1MCwYNIZCNjC1PCYAAGZFeVHogobbG4-GcCaraDrQ6ZMkpKqJIA).

Comment: The same thing but a slightly different way of expressing it which might be clearer:

         constructor() {
                this.priceList = {} as { [fruit in Fruit]: number };
                this.stock = {} as { [fruit in Fruit]: number };

                fruits.forEach(f => {
                    this.priceList[f] = 1;
                    this.stock[f] = 0;
                })
            }